# some questions about Mongodb.Aggregate variable

Tags: mongodb

here is my document:

```
members: [
    {
        _id: 'id1'
        name: 'Jack',
        group: 0
    },
    {
        _id: 'id2'
        name: 'Rose',
        group: 0
    },
    {
        _id: 'id3'
        name: 'Tom',
        group: 1
    }
]
```

I want to search all members of someone's group and the total number of all members by memberId.

For example,when i input `id1`, it will return:

```
{
  count: 3,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 'id1',
      name: 'Jack'
    },
    {
      _id: 'id2',
      name: 'Rose'
    }
  ]
}
```

when i input `id3`,it will return:

```
{
  count: 3,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 'id3',
      name: 'Tom'
    }
  ]
}
```

i tried to do this:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  $project: {
    count: {$size: '$members'},
    members: 1
  }
}, 
{
  $unwind: '$members'
},
{
  $project: {
    count: 1,
    members: {
      $cond: [{$eq: ['$members._id', TheInputMemberId]}, '$member', null]
    }
  }
})
```

But, the filter just contain `_id` not `_id` and `group`,so the result is always only one member.

I don't know how to get the group variable first and then do filter.

Looking forward to your reply!Thanks!

Comment: why input id1 returns id2 member in the first example ?

Comment: @Veeram beacuse they are in same group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Added the project and group stage to keep the data results if any of result element matches on the id passed.

***[$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)*** applies an equals comparison between the id passed and id in each data result element and generates an array with true and false values. ***[$anyElementTrue](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)*** inspects this array and returns true only if there is atleast one true value in the array. Match stage to include only elements with matched value of true.

```
aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "count": {
      "$size": "$members"
    },
    "members": 1
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$members"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$members.group",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "name": "$members.name",
        "_id": "$members._id"
      }
    },
    "count": {
      "$first": "$count"
    }
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "data": 1,
    "matched": {
      "$anyElementTrue": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$data",
          "as": "result",
          "in": {
            "$eq": ['$$result._id', 'id1']
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "matched": true
  }
}).pretty()
```

Alternative Version:

Similar to the above version but this one combines both the project and match stage into one. The ***[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)*** with ***[$redact](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)*** accounts for match and when match is found it keeps the complete tree or else discards it.

```
aggregate({
    "$project": {
        "count": {
            "$size": "$members"
        },
        "members": 1
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$members"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$members.group",
        "data": {
            "$push": {
                "name": "$members.name",
                "_id": "$members._id"
            }
        },
        "count": {
            "$first": "$count"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$redact": {
        "$cond": [{
                "$anyElementTrue": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$data",
                        "as": "result",
                        "in": {
                            "$eq": ['$$result._id', 'id1']
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "$$KEEP",
            "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Tanks a lot!I can understand your first version,the second still have to continue to study,because I don't quite understand the usage of $redact

Comment: now,i have understood the version2 and i have two small advice for your anwser. 1. the Data in Group can be {$push: "$members"} 2.the $eq is not necessary in version 2,because the $anyElementTrue just return Boolean value. sorry,my English is not well,that's all.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Will verify and update changes accordingly.

Comment: Updated. For the first edit, it can't be just members b/c that will include group field too in the output.